# Using postfix increment in an L-value

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what order does evaluation of post-increment operator happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538562/in-what-order-does-evaluation-of-post-increment-operator-happen)

Consider the following snippet(in C):

```
uint8_t index = 10;
uint8_t arr[20];

arr[index++] = index;
```

When I compile this with gcc, it sets arr[10] to 10, which means that the postfix increment isn't being applied until after the entire assignment expression. I found this somewhat surprising, as I was expecting the increment to return the original value(10) and then increment to 11, thereby setting arr[10] to 11.

I've seen lots of other posts about increment operators in RValues, but not in LValue expressions.

Thanks.

Comment: But these other post should have pointed you to the concept that is used in C to regulate the validity of such expressions, namely sequence points, no? After reading all these, you should be able to emit a qualified guess.

Comment: -1 for useless sequent point question of the day. See the above two comments for my justification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some [standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) language:

> **6.5 Expressions**
>
> 1 An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies computation of a
> value, or that designates an object or a function, or that generates side effects, or that
> performs a combination thereof.
>
> 2 Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
> modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.<sup>72)</sup> Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.<sup>73)</sup>
>
> 3 The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.<sup>74)</sup> Except as specified later (for the function-call **()**, **&&**, **||**, **?:**, and comma operators), the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified.

Paragraph 2 explicitly renders expressions of the form `a[i++] = i` undefined; the prior value of `i` isn't just being read to determine the result of `i++`.  Thus, *any* result is allowed.

Beyond that, you cannot rely on the side effect of the `++` operator to be applied immediately after the expression is evaluated.  For an expression like

```
a[i++] = j++ * ++k
```

the only guarantee is that the *result* of the expression `j++ * ++k` is assigned to the *result* of the expression `a[i++]`; however, each of the subexpressions `a[i++]`, `j++`, and `++k` may be *evaluated* in any order, and the side effects (assigning to `a[i]`, updating `i`, updating `j`, and updating `k`) may be applied in any order.

Comment: Here, you said i++, j++ and ++k can be evaluated in any order. But doesn't the associativity of '*' makes it necessary to evaluate j++ before ++k?

Comment: Precedence and associativity only guarantee how expressions are *parsed*.  For an expression like `a + b * c`, all that's guaranteed is that the *result* of `b * c` is added to the result of `a`.  The order in which the individual subexpressions `a`, `b`, and `c` are evaluated is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
arr[index++] = index;
```

causes undefined behaviour. Read the C standard for more details.

The essence you should know is: You should never read and change a variable in the same statement.

Comment: There are two `+` too much in your text ;-)

Comment: This question is regarding C, specifically. The C standard may not define the behavior either, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Sorry i edited my answer. I meant the C99 standard

Comment: I really do not know the details and I think it does not matter as long as you play by the rules.

Comment: @frast: I was talking of the same `++` as N 1.1, so it is ok now.

Comment: Section 6.5.16 of the C99 standard(The Assignment Operator) says: "The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified." Which would seem to support frast's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment operation works from right to left, i.e. right part of expression calculated first and then it is assigned to the left part.

Comment: First of all, the operation is undefined per section 6.5, para 2, so *any* result is allowed.  Secondly, per section 6.5, para 3, the order in which expressions are evaluated (and side effects applied) between any two sequence points is *unspecified*; you cannot guarantee a particular order of evaluation except for certain operators (function-call `()`, `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and comma operators, which all guarantee left-to-right evaluation).