# C pointer with postfix increment operator

Tags: c

I have a question about the postfix increment operator on C pointer, my test code as below:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[16] = {0};
    int *head = &a[0];
    int i;

    head++;

    for(i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        *head++ = head[-1] + 2;
        printf("head[-1] = %d, a[%d] = %d\n", head[-1], i, a[i]);
    }
}
```

and I compile it with GCC 5.4, the result as below:

```
head[-1] = 2, a[0] = 0

head[-1] = 2, a[1] = 2

...

head[-1] = 2, a[13] = 2

head[-1] = 2, a[14] = 2
```

what i expect is `a[0]=0, a[1]=2, a[2]=4...`.

Is it an undefined behavior like [Using postfix increment in an L-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978625/using-postfix-increment-in-an-l-value)?

Comment: When I compile the above, my compiler gives this warning:  temp.c:13:14: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'head' [-Wunsequenced]   (and indicates the problem is with the ++ in *head++ and head[-1])

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: head++; should change to *head++ line 6;

Comment: Note that `-1` is *not* the problem. `*head = head[-1] + 2 ; head++;` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* undefined behavior, but it's not because of postfix increment operator. It's a matter of [evaluation order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order).

```
*head++ = head[-1] + 2;
```

There's no specification whether `head` will be incremented first or `head[-1]` will be evaluated first (sequenced before). *That*'s the UB part of your code.

From the [community draft n1570](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5), Section 6.5/2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, **the behavior is undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

`*head++ = head[-1] + 2;` invoked [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the modification to `head`pointer on left side of the assignment operator is not sequenced before or after the use of `head` pointer on right hand side of the expression.

GCC Compiler generated warning :

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:12:14: warning: operation on 'head' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
         *head++ = head[-1] + 2;
          ~~~~^~
```

**C11: 6.5 Expressions:**

> **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined.** If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
>   subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
>   unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.84).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I did changes in my answer.